# How to mount Veracrypt volumes from disk image

Tags: disk-image, disk-encryption, hard-drive-recovery, veracrypt

I've got a broken disk which is encrypted with Veracrypt.
The problem is, the disk is encrypted in *system encryption*/*preboot authentication* mode. This seems to imply Veracrypt needs access to the whole drive when I want to mount a single partition on the drive.

What exactly does it look for?

Now, when I try to use Veracrypt on the image, it doesn't know how to automatically derive the name of the disk image. For real drives this is easy:

```
/dev/sda3 -> /dev/sda
```

But if I use `kpartx` to create `/dev/mapper/loop1p1` Veracrypt doesn't know where to find the disk image.

My only idea is to copy the whole image to another disk... Will try as soon as I read the complete image (takes several days at 2.9 MB/s)

Any other ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution for me was:

*my problem was that the extended partition table had been overridden and so I did not know the start of the partition*

**(!) This solution requires hexediting the partition table. You need to carefully read the MBR docs.**

- backup the broken disk:

  - completely dump the bad device into an image file using safecopy
  - write this image to a new drive with at least the same size
  - keep the image somewhere safe, so you may apply the unmodified image again if something went wrong
- find the start of the veracrypt partition:

  - Mount the partition using `sudo veracrypt /dev/sd<XX> -m ro -m system -p <password>`
  - if this doesn't work, experiment with different entries in partition table
- if it finally works, just copy the files somewhere safe.